# Syntax Error in in a python program with a displayed menu

Tags: python, menu, syntax-error

I am learning Python for the first time. I have a syntax error and I can not figure out if I have coded wrong or if I have just had a simple typo. I have pulled the menu out and put into a new window and the syntax error is something to do with my coding of the menu. I believe it is somewhere near the coding display menu(). If the answer it found I would greatly appreciate an explanation of why it was incorrect. (There may be some other errors in the coding but, I am stuck on the menu. After that I will work on any other issues that come up. Suggestions though would be appreciated.)

```
    #This program allow for the user to convert weight managements

#Import Modules
import KilogramConversion
import PoundConversion
import TonConversion

    #Menu choice constants

CONVERT_KILOGRAMS_OUNCE=1
CONVERT_KILOGRAMS_POUND=2
CONVERT_POUND_OUNCE=3
CONVERT_POUND_TON=4
CONVERT_TON_POUND=5
CONVERT_TON_OUNCE=6
CONVERT_TON_KILOGRAMS=7
QUIT_CHOICE=8

    # Main Function
def main():
    choice=0

while choice != QUIT_CHOICE:
    display menu()
    choice=int(input('Enter your choice:'))

    #Perform menu choice
    if choice == CONVERT_KILOGRAMS_OUNCE:
        kilo=float(input("Enter weight in Kilograms:"))
        print('The weight in ounces is:', KilogramConversion.ounce(kilo))
    elif choice == CONVERT_KILOGRAMS_POUND:
        kilo=float(input("Enter weight in Kilograms:"))
        print('The weight in pounds is:', KilogramConversion.pound(kilo))
    elif choice == CONVERT_POUND_OUNCE:
        lbs=float(input("Enter weight in Pounds:"))
        print('The weight in ounces is:', PoundConversion.ounce(lbs))
    elif choice == CONVERT_POUND_TON:
        lbs=float(input("Enter weight in Pounds:"))
        print('The weight in tons is:', PoundConversion.ton(lbs))
    elif choice == CONVERT_TON_POUND:
        tons= float(input("Enter weight in Tons:"))
        print('The weight in pounds is:', TonConversion.pound(tons))
    elif choice == CONVERT_TON_OUNCE:
        tons= float(input("Enter weight in Tons:"))
        print('The weight in ounces is:', TonConversion.ounce(tons))
    elif choice == CONVERT_TON_KILOGRAMS:
        tons= float(input("Enter weight in Tons:"))
        print('The weight in kilograms is:', TonConversion.kilogram(tons))
    elif choice == QUIT_CHOICE:
        print('Exiting...')
    else:
        print('Invalid Selection')

def display menu():
    print('          ')
    print('          ')
    print('          Menu')
    print('1. Kilograms to Ounce')
    print('2. Kilograms to Pound')
    print('3. Pound to Ounce')
    print('4. Pound to Ton')
    print('5. Ton to Pound')
    print('6. Ton to Ounce')
    print('7. Ton to Kilograms')
    print('8. Quit')

main()
```

Comment: What is the exact error message, and which line is it pointing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a function name which contains a space , replace it with an underscore `_` , it should work.

See Python [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). The rules for naming variables have to followed strictly.

***1)*** Function names should be lowercase, with **words separated by underscores and not spaces** as necessary to improve readability.

***2)*** mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style
Variables...

So your updated code will look like this:

```
    #This program allow for the user to convert weight MANAGEMENTS

#Import Modules
import KilogramConversion
import PoundConversion
import TonConversion

    #Menu choice constants

CONVERT_KILOGRAMS_OUNCE=1
CONVERT_KILOGRAMS_POUND=2
CONVERT_POUND_OUNCE=3
CONVERT_POUND_TON=4
CONVERT_TON_POUND=5
CONVERT_TON_OUNCE=6
CONVERT_TON_KILOGRAMS=7
QUIT_CHOICE=8

    # Main Function
def main():
    choice=0

    while choice != QUIT_CHOICE:
       display_menu()
       choice=int(input('Enter your choice:'))

       #Perform menu choice
       if choice == CONVERT_KILOGRAMS_OUNCE:
          kilo=float(input("Enter weight in Kilograms:"))
          print('The weight in ounces is:', KilogramConversion.ounce(kilo))
       elif choice == CONVERT_KILOGRAMS_POUND:
          kilo=float(input("Enter weight in Kilograms:"))
          print('The weight in pounds is:', KilogramConversion.pound(kilo))
       elif choice == CONVERT_POUND_OUNCE:
          lbs=float(input("Enter weight in Pounds:"))
          print('The weight in ounces is:', PoundConversion.ounce(lbs))
       elif choice == CONVERT_POUND_TON:
          lbs=float(input("Enter weight in Pounds:"))
          print('The weight in tons is:', PoundConversion.ton(lbs))
       elif choice == CONVERT_TON_POUND:
          tons= float(input("Enter weight in Tons:"))
          print('The weight in pounds is:', TonConversion.pound(tons))
       elif choice == CONVERT_TON_OUNCE:
          tons= float(input("Enter weight in Tons:"))
          print('The weight in ounces is:', TonConversion.ounce(tons))
       elif choice == CONVERT_TON_KILOGRAMS:
          tons= float(input("Enter weight in Tons:"))
          print('The weight in kilograms is:', TonConversion.kilogram(tons))
       elif choice == QUIT_CHOICE:
           print('Exiting...')
       else:
           print('Invalid Selection')

def display_menu():
    print('          ')
    print('          ')
    print('          Menu')
    print('1. Kilograms to Ounce')
    print('2. Kilograms to Pound')
    print('3. Pound to Ounce')
    print('4. Pound to Ton')
    print('5. Ton to Pound')
    print('6. Ton to Ounce')
    print('7. Ton to Kilograms')
    print('8. Quit')

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and the resource! That will be extremely helpful I learning from home and so far I have been my own main resource.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Andrea glad I could help :) I suggest you to go through some great tutorials on youtube(thats how i learnt). Good luck learning Python and Happy Coding ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Line 24: you called `display menu()` instead of `display_menu()`. Also, you need to define `display_menu()` before calling it.